# How to attach interface to a fragment, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to attach the interface, but I only know one way to do it:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            myInterface=context as MyInterface
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("myLog",e.message)
        }
    }
```

But in this case, the interface can only be used in the Main Activity. And I need to use it in the ViewModel. Question is: How can this be implemented? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean the instance of the interface in the Activity, you can put a setter method inside viewModel. Then you can use it freely.

In the viewModel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){
    private var mInterface: MyInterface? = null 

    fun setInterface(myInt: MyInterface){
        mInterface = myInt
    }
}
```

in activity:

```
override fun onCreate(...){
     viewModel.setInterface(this)
}
```

Comment: Do you plan to `null` out that interface in `onDestroy`?

Comment: But then problem is that in Main Activity I cannot get a reference to the viewModel, because I created it with View Model Factory

Comment: the owner of viewmodel is activity so it should not be problem. In Activity, you should do val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { myViewModelFactory}